# How to (cheaply) grind wheat berries for home bread making?

Tags: bread, flour, wheat

I've never made wheat flour before, though I bake bread regularly. I'm considering using my [KitchenAid blender](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00NPZHN1G) to grind my hard white wheat berries, but am worried I would harm the blender. I use about 7 cups of flour per week, so [hand-milling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0018P54TS) might be too labor-intensive. Is there a good way I could try out homemade flour without investing in an expensive grinding device? If not, what grinding device is recommended for home use?

As a bonus, I'd like to use the device for occasionally grinding chicken feed...

Comment: What do you consider "cheaply"?  There are some manual grain mills available in the $100 price range, and some of those then have kits to upgrade them to add a motor  (there are less expensive ones, but they're often just for coarse grinding, like for corn meal or grinding for brewing, not for flour).

Comment: $100 or less is what I'm thinking. Or better yet, $0 - I'm curious if I could use something that I already have around the house to see if I enjoy the process and experience of home-milled flour before spending on a gadget.

Comment: Traditionally old fashioned coffee grinders are used, but those do run on muscle power. And take a lot of time as it is hard work. I did buy a second hand traditional style (but relatively new) one in a second hand market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a carona mill for under $50.  It looks like this:

[image]

But you are likely going to work pretty hard, and have to do plenty of sifting. I have one and it is fairly inconsistent, as the plates and mechanism are hard to dial in, and have a tendency to loosen. It is good enough to get you started with some experiments, though.